# Load Keras library in Jupiter notebook using virtual environment

Tags: python, keras, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv

I installed TensorFlow and Keras using virtual environment as explained [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac) and [here](https://keras.io/#installation).
Then inside the virtual environment I installed Jupyter notebook and executed this command to create a new kernel:

```
ipython kernel install --name "jupyter3_Python_3" --user
```

When I run `jupyter-notebook` from the console and change the kernel to `jupyter3_Python_3` in Jupyter notebook, I get the following error:

[image]

It looks like `keras` in not installed.
However, when I run `python` from the virtual environment and do `import keras`, then everything works.
I assume that I incorrectly launch Jupyter notebook, therefore it does not get access to the virtual environment. But I followed all instructions. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try to first enter your virtual environment from the console:

```
source /var/venv/virtual_environment/bin/activate # or whatever your path is
```

and then run `jupyter notebook`

Comment: This is what I did. I entered into the virtual environment `(tensorflow)`and then I ruined jupyter-notebook.

Comment: have you pip install keras inside virtual environment?

Comment: Yes, I tried both `Python 3` that comes by default, and `jupyter3_Python_3` that I created. Keras is unavailable in both kernels.